# How to create Interface for Nested JSON Object

Tags: json, angular, interface

I am having a Nested JSON Object and I need to create the Interface and Use that in my TS File...

```
    {
        "states":[
    
            {
                "location":"banglore",
                "weather":{
                    "place":{
                        "heat":40,
                        "cold":60,
                        "place":"banglore"
                    }
                }
            },
            ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
`export interface States{

      "states":[
    {   
        "location": string,
        "weather":{
                "place":{
                        "heat":number,
                        "cold":number,
                        "place":string
                }   }
    }
]
  }`
```